# Refreshing a page opened with window.location.replace or window.open(url,'_self') takes me to previous window

Tags: html, google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, window.open

I have a published google web app that I am using as a splash screen.  When I click a button on this screen it correctly takes me to the page (using either of the methods below).  When I refresh that page, however, it returns me to the splash screen instead of keeping me on the newly opened screen, as I'd like it to do.  I thought window.location.replace would correct this, but it is still doing it.

I have tried window.open(myurl,'_self') and window.location.replace(myurl) and it keeps happening.  If I create a new tab with just window.open(myurl) and I refresh that, it keeps me on the correct page.  I would prefer to not have the user open a bunch of tabs for this to work correctly.  Is there something I am missing to make this refresh to the page that was opened with the window command?

Comment: GAS web-apps are sandboxed in iframes. When you click a link in that iframe it is changing the source of that iframe. When you refresh it reloads the main page which has no knowledge of the state the embedded iframe is in. If you share some source there might be a way to get it to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your app is loaded in a sandboxed iframe, you should use

```
window.open(myurl,'_top')
```

to load in the top frame