# How to logout Google Web App and redirect to its login page

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google web app (created with google app script) in my G-Suite account. Permissions are set to Execute the app as: Me / Who has access to the app: Anyone

The app upon launch detects user logged in with organization account (domain: bcas.du.ac.in). I have placed a signout button to log out of google account. It successfully logs out but does not reload the app to google login page and the page appears blank. On refreshing the blank page manually it displays the desired google login options and upon login launches the app. I am using the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function LogOut()
 {  

 var newWindow = window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=fr','Disconnect from Google','width=500,height=400,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=200');
 setTimeout(function(){
    if (newWindow) newWindow.close();
    var url = "https://script.google.com/a/bcas.du.ac.in/macros/s/project-id/exec" + "&output=embed";
   var url = url.replace("watch?v=", "v/");
   window.location.replace(url);
    },3000);

   }
   </script>
```

It shows the following error

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/a/bcas.du.ac.in/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=12…s%2Fproject-id%2Fexec%26output%3Dembed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

Is there a way to auto refresh after logout.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google apps script location.reload in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674502/google-apps-script-location-reload-in-web-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refreshing a page opened with window.location.replace or window.open(url,'\_self') takes me to previous window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60607091/refreshing-a-page-opened-with-window-location-replace-or-window-openurl-self)

Comment: I tried to implement the suggestion but it does not work. Getting the following error.

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://script.google.com/macros/s/script-id/exec does not permit cross-origin framing.

Comment: The answer in the second suggestion seems to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working for me. Clicking logout button executes the LogOut() function. A new window pops up, and automatically closes in few seconds. Then the app page displays Google login options. Upon login it reloads the app.

```
function LogOut()
{  
  var newWindow = window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/?logout&hl=fr','Disconnect from Google','width=500,height=400,menubar=no,status=no,location=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,top=200,left=200');
setTimeout(function()
{
  if (newWindow) newWindow.close();
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/project-id/exec"
  window.open(url, '_top')
 },3000);
```

}

Comment: Since my above post everything was working fine. Now suddenly since few weeks the app is not reloading after logout and have to be manually reloaded. Following message appears in error console:

The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

Any suggestions on what changed and how to rectify the issue?